# display div on hover of another div without having same parent

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to display a div if another div which doesn't share the same parent is hovered.
The html looks something like this:

```
<div class="test">
   <div class="hover-me"><p>Hover</p></div>
</div>

// some other content here

<div class="hover-content">
 <p>hovered content</p>
</div>
```

I've tried using

```
.test:hover + .hover-content { 
    display: block;
}
```

But I think this only works if there's no other content in-between? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i think it will help you :

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () { 
          $( ".hover-me" ).mouseenter( function () { 
               $( ".hover-content" ).show();
           }).mouseout(function () {
               /*anything you want when mouse leaves the div*/
           } ); 
       }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Since the "hover-me" div has at least one child element, `mouseenter` can potentially not be triggered for this div when the mouse goes over the child element(s).  `mouseenter` does not bubble up to the parents, and with the right styling, it is possible, and likely, for the mouse to enter a child without going through the parent.  Use `mouseover` or `hover` instead - as I did in my earlier answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to listen to the onmouseover event, or jquery to handle the hover event on one and change the display attribute of the other.  Using jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".hover-me").hover(function () {
            $(".hover-content").show();
        }, function() {
            $(".hover-content").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you don't want to use jquery, change your html like so

```
<div class="test">
   <div class="hover-me"
      onmouseover="document.getElementById('hover-content').style.display = 'block';"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('hover-content').style.display = 'none';">
   <p>Hover</p></div>
</div>

// some other content here

<div class="hover-content" id="hover-content">
 <p>hovered content</p>
</div>
```

notice that I added an id attribute to the hover-content div.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display the .hover-content when you hover the test. You can try the following solution. If it does not work, you gotta use javascript to check for the mouseover event. Hope it helps!

```
 .test:hover ~ .hover-content {
   display: block;
 }
```

Comment: This should not work.  The general sibling combinator (`~`) does not work unless the two elements are siblings (share the same parent) which OP said is not the case

Comment: I think test and hover-content are siblings of each other

Comment: OP said "another div which doesn't share the same parent".  So they are not siblings.